# REST API design best practice for nested resources

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to design an API for an existing database schema but I'm struggling a bit with nested resources and (possible) recursion.

So, given the following models:-

```
CourseType
   - id
   - name

Event
   - id
   - date
   - course type

Booking
   - id
   - event
```

I'd expect my API to have (roughly) the following URIs:-

```
/api/course_types
/api/course_types/{id}
/api/course_types/{id}/events

/api/events
/api/events/{id}
/api/events/{id}/bookings

/api/bookings
/api/bookings/{id}
```

which is fine. But I can imagine a scenario where someone wants to list all the events that are associated with a specific course type AND all their bookings. So the call to  would have to /api/course_types/{id}/events would have to expand all the bookings of each event as well as all the other details.

But I can also imagine that, when fetching a particular booking, the user might want to get that booking's event details. Which could lead to a recursive situation where each event's bookings are being expanded and returned and each booking's event is being expanded etc.

What is the best way to design an API with this in mind?